# Bandstop butterworth filter

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing, butterworth

I'm trying to create a bandstop butterworth filter using the scipy library in python, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? `fc1` is `1750`, `fc2` is `4100`, `fs` is `30000` and `ft` is `150`. I have defined them(`fc` is the union of everything outside the cutoff frequencies interval, `fc1` and `fc2`, `ft` is the time frequency, `rp` and `rs` are the passband and the stopband ripples, `a` is the amplitude, `wp(passband)`, `ws(stopband)` and `wn` are normalized frequencies).

My error:

```
ValueError: Wn must specify start and stop frequencies for bandpass or bandstop filter.
```

This is what i have until now as code:
    fs = 33000 
    r = 55
    ft = 150
    rp = 0.3
    rs = 55
    order = 3
    a=1
    fc1 = 1750
    fc2 = 4100
    fc=np.union1d(np.array([1,1750]),([4100,10000]))
    wp = (fc1-ft/2) *2/fs

```
ws = (fc2 + ft/2) *2/fs

N, wn = sp.buttord(wp, ws, rp, rs)

b, a = sp.butter(N, wn , btype = "bandstop")

w,h = sp.freqz(b, a,  worN=512, plot=None)

f=(fs/2)*w/(np.pi)

plt.figure()

plt.plot(f,abs(h))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider improving your question, since `fc` and its friends could be whatever and therefore it is not clear what are you trying to achieve.
From the point of syntax and signal processing, one needs to define a bandpass/bandstop filter you should specify 4 points, because the filter has bell-like shape. Please, refer to [buttord parameters](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.buttord.html#scipy.signal.buttord):

> `wp`, `ws` : float
>   bandstop: `wp = [0.1, 0.6]`, `ws = [0.2, 0.5]`

so `wp` and `ws` should have shape of (2,).
To make the syntax in your example correct, change

```
wp = (fc1-ft/2) *2/fs
ws = (fc2 + ft/2) *2/fs
```

to

```
wp = [(fc1-ft/2) *2/fs, (fc2 + ft) *2/fs]
ws = [(fc1+ft) *2/fs, (fc2 + ft/2) *2/fs]
```

The frequencies, of course, are chosen arbitrarily, but keep in mind that it must be 
`wp_low < ws_low < ws_high < wp_high` so pass range includes stop range entirely.